# How to use Regex to find a string with only spaces delimiting it?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a string that is only whitespace delimited.

I am currently using **`/\b[somestring]\b/`**

But i don't want it to pick up words that have **any punctuation next to it.**

So if i parsed this string:

```
"Trying to,\n
test this out,\n
but Trying to do this has taken a while.\n
Trying to do stuff is fun,\n
but i am stuck"
```

with **`/\bTrying To\b/`**

I find three, but i only want two because i don't want to include

```
"Trying to,"
```

--Edit

Expected output

```
Trying To
Trying To
```

Comment: You trying to find `Trying to`?

Comment: `\s(Trying to)\s` ?

Comment: @0m3r Yes i am trying to find "Trying to"

Comment: @ryugie Yes that does work, however if the string starts with with 
**"Trying To"** it will not find that string.

Comment: Can you write your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly  your question, then you can use a regex lookahead like this:

```
Trying to(?=\s)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Vpsbkb/1)**

The idea is to search for your string `Trying to` that is following with a space character

Edit: if you want to include those having `\n`, then you can use:

```
Trying to(?=\s|\\n)
```

Btw, if you want to include the literal space and the literal `\n`, then you don't need to use a regex lookahead, but simple group like this:

```
Trying to(?:\s|\\n)
```

Comment: That does work, but i made a slight mistake in my question and have edit it. I actually do want to include with tokens with a "\n"

So matching a string 
**something something Trying to\n**
should pick up as well

Comment: @Jorge, I've udpated the answer

Comment: Thanks @Ferderico Piazza you rock! One side question before you go, how do i only find the first occurrence using regex?

Comment: @Jorge, you can use your language to do that, with java you iterate using a matcher. Regex is a matter/matcher tool, but when need logic you use something else to help, for iterating and get the first match you can use a for loop, or just an if statement

Comment: gotcha, i'll look into it @Ferderico Piazza

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding what you want, but should this work? `/(?:^| )Trying to /gm`, if you don't want all matches you could get rid of the `g` flag but please note this answer requires the `m` flag if you want new lines to work. Or if for some reason you don't want to deal with regex flags the following should work: `/(?:^|\n| )Trying to /`.